# How to add RelativeLayout into another RelativeLayout through Java?

Tags: java, android

I have been researching on how to add a `RelativeLayout` inside another `RelativeLayout` with id `content`. But I'm still not able to do so. I'm getting error on `content.addView(insert);` and I cannot assign a background to it. Please Help.

Also is there any way I can simple insert `XML` written text in `String` format which contains the `RelativeLayout` and its properties to the `RelativeLayout, id=content`?

`MainActivity.java:`

```
package com.example.flexbox;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RelativeLayout content;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        content = findViewById(R.id.content);

        //<RelativeLayout
        //        android:id="@+id/video_player_box"
        //        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        //        android:layout_height="400dp"
        //        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        //        android:background="@color/black">
        //</RelativeLayout>

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams insert = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 400);
        insert.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
        content.addView(insert);
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_black"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="800dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set Dy manically relative layout inside another relative layout

try this code of lines:

**xml Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/rel_main"
android:gravity="center">

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initView();

}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private void initView() {

    //main relative layout
    relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.rel_main);

    RelativeLayout rel_1 = new RelativeLayout(MainActivity.this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(400, 400);
    rel_1.setLayoutParams(lp);  // set layout paramsA
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    relativeLayout.addView(rel_1);  // add releative in main layout
    rel_1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);   // se relative background color

}
```

}

**below screen shot**
[image]

it helps you

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things you're doing wrong.

**First,** the way to create a View through Java code is very different from XML.

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(MainActivity.this);
```

You can set the id through:

`relativeLayout.setId(R.id.video_player_box)`

However, since this isn't through xml, if you want to use the `video_player_box` id, you'll need to first create this id yourself.

So in your `values` folder, create an `ids.xml` file and inside add in this new id:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="video_player_box" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

This will automatically generate an 'id' for you to use in your R resources.

The `width`, `height`, and alignments are all stored in the `LayoutParams`, so you'll need to create a `LayoutParams` meant for `RelativeLayout.`

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.video_player_height));
layoutParams.topMargin = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.video_player_top_margin);
```

Finally, just set background directly to the layout:

```
layout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
```

You can insert all of that directly to the content RelativeLayout by:

```
content.addView(relativeLayout, layoutParams);
```

This way, RelativeLayout will be added to content with the new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams you created for it.

**Second,** you cannot use `setBackgroundResource` onto a LayoutParams because it doesn't support that. LayoutParams is meant to store a different type of data.

**Third,** you can't use `content.addView(insert)` because your insert is a LayoutParams. `addView()` is meant to add a View, so it won't work if you use it to add a LayoutParams.